# Meta HTTP Refresh Safe or Not?

Tags: html, refresh, meta-tags

i use meta http-equiv= refresh in my website to kick out the unregistered people to login page. For instance i have a place only for members who are logged in, and i redirect the people who want to see there with meta refresh to login page. But i want to learn that is it possible to break that and see the content there anonymously?

I'm using my function like

```
if($session == true){

// content

}

else{
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=\"mywebsite.com/login\" />";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you attach some of your code here?

Comment: Just set the `header` location. That will always work.

Comment: If you don't send user-only content but only the refresh, the privacy should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and very easy. For instance, simply pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> when getting redirected will stop the redirect.

In general, you cannot rely on client-side techniques to prevent unauthorized accesses. The moment your Web server sends private information to the browser, you can consider its privacy compromised.

The only way to protect the content is to check on the server side that the user is logged in before outputting any content to the browser.

In PHP, you can do this before any content is sent:

```
if (!$session) {
    header("Location: //mywebsite.com/login", true, 302);
    die("Not authenticated, redirecting..."); // stop the script
}
// content
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i added some code, so is it possible to break mine ?

Comment: Partly, just pressing the escape key will prevent the redirect. but here you have protected the content by putting a condition around it, so it will stop the redirect but not display the content.